# re-initializing PLY parser

Tags: python, parsing, ply

I wrote a parser using PLY and it does what I need.
Now, I would like to parse multiple files using the parser class.
Instead of instantiating the parser class for each file, I would like to re-use the same instantiated class for all files (so that I can accumulate some results in the parser class).

Parsing of one file may not complete nicely so that I would like to re-initialize the parser before feeding another file.

What is the correct way to re-initialize a PLY parser?
(Or, I shouldn't reuse a parser?)

Comment: (Disclaimer:  I don't use PLY.)  You might get more answers if you give examples of the kinds of data you want to keep, and why.  If PLY _does_ have a safe re-init method, I doubt it will leave _un_-re-initialized the exact values you want to keep.  ...  For that matter, wouldn't you be better off accumulating the data you want to keep from each parser in a dictionary, or maybe in one dictionary per parsed file?

Comment: I'm writing a Verilog parser and it will process multiple Verilog files. Some of them may contain errors so that parser may stop in a funny state when a file is parsed. I thought it might be a good idea to reuse the parser so that no need to tear down the parser object and build a new parser object. Also, I can keep parsed results from multiple input files in the class.

Comment: "Some of them may contain errors so that parser may stop in a funny state", combined with "I can keep parsed results from multiple input files", sounds like you will be mixing errors from the first kind of file into the good results in the second.  But I'm out of my domain here, so I'll leave this question to someone else.  I suggest, though, that you [edit] the details from your comment into your question --- they won't be noticed down here.

Comment: Pyparsing includes a verilog parser as part of its examples - even if you still choose to use PLY, this code might give you some insights into what you need in your own parser implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the same parser for multiple files, but reset the stack each time, you can use the `restart` function:

```
parser = yacc.yacc()
for file in file_list:
    with open(file) as fp:
       parser.parse(fp.read())
       ... # accumulate logging info
       parser.restart() # this discards the entire parsing stack and resets the parser to its initial state
```

More can be found at the [official documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html).